# Como eu faço para transformar uma classe em um texto clicável?

Tags: html, classes, text

Está aqui a classe que eu queria transformar num texto clicável

```
 <li class="content__container__list__item">Select a Language !</li>
```

Eu espero que alguém me diga como posso fazer isso!

Comment: E o que você espera que aconteça ao clicar no elemento?

Comment: Vc quer que o texto "Select a Language !" seja um link para outra página? Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara....

Comment: Sim, quero isso!

Comment: Por favor, elabore um [mcve] e descreva qual é o resutado desejado. **Importante**: faça isso editando a pergunta, não pelos comentários.

Comment: Já resolvi o meu problema, pode por favor ver este link e responder![Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55567961/11333864)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta foi um pouco vaga, mas vamos lá... Eu entendo duas coisas por um "texto clicável":
1. um texto que mude o mouse quando você passa sobre ele e mude a cor do texto quando você clica;
2. um texto que execute determinados comandos, geralmente abrir links.
Caso queira abrir links, o HTML tem uma tag própria pra isso: a [tag <a>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).
Mas considerando seu código, vamos tentar o seguinte:

```js
// Se você só quiser estilizar (duvido muito), CSS e HTML bastam, caso contrário, JS será necessário:

// Quando a página terminar de carregar...
window.onload = function(){
  // Crio uma variável pro nome da classe (pq n to afim de ficar escrevendo :v)
  var classe = 'content__container__list__item';
  // Encontro o primeiro elemento [0] pelo nome da classe
  var li = document.getElementsByClassName(classe)[0];
  
  // Ao clicar no elemento...
  li.onclick = function(){
    // Aqui vai oq você quer que o código faça
    // Eu só vou mudar a cor do fundo pra um ciano
    li.style.background = '#0FF';
  };
};
```

```css
.content__container__list__item {
  color: black;     /* Cor padrão do texto: Preto */
  cursor: pointer;  /* O mouse vai virar aquela "mãozinha" que estamos acostumados pra botões */
  padding: 5px; /* Define a margem interna */
}


/* Quando o mouse estiver sobre o texto */

.content__container__list__item:hover {
  color: #666;    /* Cor do texto: cinza escuro */
  text-decoration: underline; /* Texto sublinhado */
}


/* Quando o usuário clicar no texto */
.content__container__list__item:active {
  color: #AAA;    /* Cor do texto: cinza claro */
  text-decoration: underline; /* Texto sublinhado */
}
```

```html
<li class="content__container__list__item">Select a Language !</li>
```

No caso da tag <a> que mencionei, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```css
/* Afeta direto o link */
.filha {
  color: black;           /* Cor: preto */
  text-decoration: none;  /* Tira o sublinhado */
  font-weight: bold;      /* Negrito só pra poder diferenciar */
}

/* Afeta todo link dentro de quem tiver a classe */
.pai a {
  color: black; /* Cor: preto */
  text-decoration: none;  /* Tira o sublinhado */
  font-weight: bold;      /* Negrito só pra poder diferenciar */
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Por padrão, a tag &lt;a&gt; <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">pega outra cor e fica sublinhado</a>,</li>
<li>mas você pode resolver isso no <a class="filha" href="https://www.w3schools.com/">CSS</a></li>
<li class="pai">dessas <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">duas formas</a></li>
</ul>
```

Espero ter sanado sua dúvida. Mas na próxima, tente ser um pouquinho mais direto ;-)

Comment: Já resolvi o meu problema, pode por favor ver este link e responder![Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55567961/11333864)

Comment: Prontinho, espero que ajude xD

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content__container__list__item:active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Agora, se o que você precisa for executar alguma ação com o evento `click` utilize JavaScript:

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("My Function");
}
```

```html
<li class="content__container__list__item" onclick="myFunction()">Select a Language !</li>
```

Comment: Sua resposta não está nos padrões mínimos de formatação

Comment: Já resolvi o meu problema, pode por favor ver este link e responder![Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55567961/11333864)